# Unable to build meteor app (Windows): \promise_server.js:116

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, meteor

More code posted here https://forums.meteor.com/t/major-node-issue-unable-to-build-meteor-app-windows-promise-server-js-116/26798/1

I get the following errors when I try to build or update an app:
When UPDATEing from 1.2.1 to any other version:

```
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\less\2.6.0\plugin.compileLessBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
            ^
Error: ENOTDIR, readdir '<projectDirectory>\.meteor\local\isopacks\.build994576.ccbanker_template-banker\web.browser\client\js\settings\.builder-tmp-file.264146'
```

When BUILDing an app - which is meteor 1.3.5.1

```
C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.9\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
          throw error;
                ^
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

I also get a similar error when I create a new empty app, and then try to BUILD it (which succeeds) and NPM INSTALL (which fails, again throwing the error at promise_server.js:116)

Have tried rebuilding all of this on a clean install of node+npm+meteor.

Comment: What version of Node.js?

Comment: have tried using 0.10.41 , 0.10.43, and 4.4.7

Answer (score 1):

Node version 0.10.40 require for npm build in meteor js. 
You can use nvm for node version change: https://github.com/creationix/nvm